# Prove that f has a simple zero at c iff certain conditions hold

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'd like to prove that the function $$f(x) = g(x)(x-c)$$ has a simple root iff $g(x)$ is continuous at $c$, differentiable on a deleted neighborhood of $c$, and $g(c) \neq 0$.

I've proven that $g(x)$ being continuous at $c$, differentiable on a deleted neighborhood of $c$, and $g(c) \neq 0$ implies that $f(x) = g(x)(x-c)$ has a simple root, but I'm having trouble proving the converse. Any suggestions on how to proceed? Hints (rather than the complete answer) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ ha a simple root at $c$ according to your definition then the function
$$g(x):={f(x)\over x-c}\quad (x\ne c),\qquad g(c):=f'(c)\ ,$$
is continuous at $c$ with $g(c)\ne0$. Furthermore $g$ is differentiable in $\dot U(c)$, and one has
$$f(x)=g(x)(x-c)\qquad\forall x\ .\tag{1}$$
Conversely: If one has $(1)$ for a function $g$ with the listed properties then $f$ is differentiable in $\dot U(c)$, continuous at $c$ with $f(c)=0$, and
$$\lim_{x\to c}{f(x)-f(c)\over x-c}=\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=g(c)\ne0\ ,$$
which implies that $f$ is differentiable at $c$ with nonzero $f'(c)$; hence $f$ has a simple zero at $c$.

Comment: I define a simple root here as a point $c$ such that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $c$, $f(c) = 0$, and $f'(c) \neq 0$.